# How to rename single raster band in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro

https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-rename-individual-raster-bands-in-arcgis-pro-000027398

I followed the instructions in this article using ArcPy, and it worked with some of my raster products but not all. They are all one-band TIFF files and the code below was the same for all other than the file names. Here is an example of one that did not work.

```
 TRI = r"D:\Auburn\Research\GIS\data_int\Testing\BushyCreek_DyasCreek\TRI\DEM03_RAW\BushyCreekDyasCreek_DEM03RAW_TRI.tif"

 rastTRI = arcpy.Raster(TRI)

 rastTRI.renameBand('Band_1','BushyCreek_DyasCreek_TRI')
```

The output remains to be 'Band_1' and I can't find any typos or other issues. Any thoughts on where this is going wrong? I am aware there is a new mosiac dataset option but I prefer ArcPy to run this code on multiple products. There was not an error message.

Comment: Aouc could try this, to check if you got any errors: import arcpy

desc_band = arcpy.Describe(r"D:\Auburn\Research\GIS\data_int\Testing\BushyCreek_DyasCreek\TRI\DEM03_RAW\BushyCreekDyasCreek_DEM03RAW_TRI.tif/Band_1")

print ("Name = " + str(desc_band.Name))
print ("Index = " + str(desc_band.primaryField))

Comment: When you say it did not work what was the error message it returned? Edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import arcpy
img_path = r"<path_to_tiff_file>"
raster = arcpy.Raster(img_path)
arcpy.env.workspace = im
bandnames = [arcpy.Raster(b) for b in arcpy.ListRasters()]
bandIndex = list(range(1,len(bandnames)+1))

rename = ['MDT', 'Slope', 'Curvature', 'Aspect', 'SPI', 'TWI','Dist2River', 'LULC']
for idx, name in zip(bandIndex, rename):
    rast.renameBand(idx, name)
```